# Increment Public Chatter Posts and Unread Public Chatter Posts

Tags: trigger

Custom field is created for Public Chatter Posts and Unread Public Chatter Posts

```
trigger CountChatterPostsOnCase on FeedItem (before insert, after insert) {
    String caseKeyPrefix = Case.sObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
    set<ID> caseIDs = new set<ID>();
    for (FeedItem f : trigger.new){
        String parentId = f.parentId;
        if (parentId != null && parentId.startsWith(caseKeyPrefix) ){
            caseIDs.add(f.parentId);
        }
    }
    if(!caseIDs.IsEmpty()){
        list<case> cslist =[Select F1 ,F2  from Case where id = :caseIDs];
        for (case cs:cslist) {
            cs.F1 = cs.F1 + 1;
            cs.F2 = cs.F2 + 1;
        }
        update cslist;
    }
}
```

Am getting error **Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments** .. can you guide me which fiels i need to take from case object to increment feeditems on posted.

Test class for the below trigger
@istest
public class CountChatterPostsOnCase{
public  static testmethod void  () {

Can you anyone guide me how to implement and getting lots error while writing..

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess as you haven't post the line on which the error is occurring, but I'm guessing it's this:

```
cs.Id = cs.Id + 1;
```

Which isn't going to work as Apex doesn't know how to increment IDs.

Try something like this:

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < cslist.size(); i++) {

    cs.Id = cslist[i+1].Id;
    cs.Case_Opened_Hour__c = cs.Case_Opened_Hour__c + 1;

}
```

Comment: can you guide me which field i need to get frm case object which is realted to chatterfeed items .. so that i can increment posted on feed items.

Comment: After this execute your code am getting this error  Invalid type: Int

Comment: try Integer instead of Int.

Comment: No problem, please mark this question as answered if you're happy with the solution.